# How to validate a treatment scheme?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, predictive-models

*The following is purely hypothetical:*

#### 1. Treatments

We have 4 treatments, let's call them A, B, C and D, for some medical condition, for which there is a 10% chance of recovery on average (given that you receive a treatment).

#### 2. Sample data

We also have completely randomized sample of, let's say, 1.000.000 observations where participants suffering from the medical condition in question were given a random treatment and their outcome was recorded.

That's to say, for each random trial, we have some variables like age, country of origin, brand of car they drive, which treatment they were given and whether or not they recovered after getting the treatment.

Since no single treatment is the best for all cases, we need to come up with a treatment scheme that maximises the probability that a patient recovers.

#### 3. Treatment scheme

A treatment scheme, let's call it treatment scheme X, might look like this:

- 58 year old patients from India who drive a Hyundai should get treatment A
- 32 year old patients from Sweden who drive a Volvo should get treatment B
- and so on, covering all cases

#### 4. Evaluation of a potential treatment scheme against the sample data

Given our data, where 1.000.000 participant were given a random treatment and the outcome recorded, how can we evaluate the probability that some percentage of patients will recover, if we apply treatment scheme X? Which of the possible X, Y and Z treatment schemes is the best?

We don't have time to do the proper experiment with X, Y and Z - we have to pick the one with the highest probability of success.

It's worthy to note that the population wide probability that a patient recovers is around 10%, but we might be able to push it up to 11% if we choose the correct treatment in each case.

#### 5. What I've tried

I've tried to use a confusion matrix, where a true positive is when the patient received the treatment I would recommend, and he recovered. However, since I'm not exactly predicting recovery or not, but just which treatment is most likely to cause recovery, I'm not sure this is a valid approach. I've not had much success with following the output of this method, which is why I want to try something else.

Another idea I'm having but haven't pursued yet is some form of an Inter-rater Reliability score, but I can't tell if one would apply, nor am I sure of how to do such a test.

Since two important variable, country and car, are categorical and I have no idea how they group together (this could be a different question), I don't find any comfort in linear regression.

#### 6. About me

I am not a trained data scientist so I might be using less than ideal vocabulary, please forgive me for that - I hope that I explain the situation well anyway. If not, let me know and I can elaborate.

If you have an answer for my problem, please be patient when explaining it - I might not be familiar with all the concepts and terminology, but I can learn fast.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding, you already have the data, and you want to analyze it.

You could use logistic regression for this.  You have a binary response variable (recovered or not), and logistic regression provides you with a probability based on the values of the predictor variables.  The details of the model will tell you which predictors (treatments) have the most impact in given situations.

It's easy to install R and R-Studio, and there are web pages on doing logistic regression with R.  You will also need to read a tutorial on getting your data into R-Studio.  It's easy if you have an XL or .csv file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already use R and R-Studio. Which package and functions do you recommend for logistic regression? You're right that I already have the data and want to analyze it. I will look into logistic regression and let you know how it works out :-)

Comment: Hi JimK39, I have not been able use logistic regression to find the solution. From what I can figure, LR is an approach to building a model that can predict classifications. This is not what I'm asking though, as I'm assuming that I already have a model that predicts the best treatment for each patient. What I need, however, is a way to calculate a score for the model - see how well it's doing when used on the sample data with known outcomes. I am looking for a concrete Scoring Function.

Comment: I'm reading that you have four treatments, A-D, which are Boolean, and an outcome, recovery, which is Boolean.  Is that correct?  If not, please clarify.  If it is, please post the R code you have tried.

Comment: The outcome is binary (Boolean), correct. I don't know what you mean by the treatment being boolean - yes, a patient either gets treatment A or doesn't, but he will always get exactly one treatment. If there's anything particular unclear about my question I'm happy to improve it.

Comment: I was clarifying that I understood your question correctly, as it seems I do.  I asked because I didn't know why you were having a problem modeling it.  Please post the R code you have tried.